# How to transform key to value and value to key in json using jolt spec?

Tags: json, jolt

I need to transform (multiple) keys to value and values to keys in JSON using jolt spec. What should be the right spec to do it?

Input :

```
{
  "k1": "v1",
  "k2": "v2"
}
```

Required Output :

```
{
  "v1": "k1",
  "v2": "k2"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should reverse key with value:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "@(0)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```